# Is there a word for "being able to write sentences" or someone that "can write better sentences"?

Tags: single-word-requests

The only word that comes to my mind, is being literate, but that is just a person that can write altogether.

Is there something for people that can write in a "better" way; someone that just writes "fancier"?

For "Mr. Dave writes really good sentences" would you just say "Mr. Dave is literate in English" or is there a word that would fit in "Mr. Dave is ~insert word here~"?

I know that "writing good sentences" is kind of subjective but I hope I could bring my point across.

Comment: *Mr. Dave is [very / highly / extremely] **articulate***. He speaks / writes very well.

Comment: I assume that it also works in the sense of `He can write *more articulate* sentences`, right?

Comment: Strictly speaking, yes. But speaking as someone who considers *himself* relatively "articulate", I think it would be better to stick to using it to describe the attribute of a *speaker / writer*, rather than extending it to the competent speaker's actual *utterances*. That might just be a personal preference, though.

Comment: I see. This answers the question. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: As Steve Martin says, “Some people have a way with words, and others…  not…  have way.”

Answer (score 2):

Mr. Dave is a wordsmith.
Mr. Dave is a good writer.

Comment: Exactly. Writing is always in sentences, so simply _writing_ does the job. But, since writing is a learned and very difficult skill (as opposed to recognizing and drawing written words), some people are better at it than others. @Rederdex: Take a look at anything by John McPhee or Terry Pratchett to see what I mean. They're both very good writers; and they do it with sentences.

Comment: @JohnLawler Ah, McPhee is the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can write

> Mr Dave can write fluently.
> Mr Dave is fluent in English.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/fluent) has

> **fluent**
> <sub>ADJECTIVE</sub>
>
> Able to express oneself easily and articulately.

---

We don't usually say that someone writes a *good sentence*. One expression is

> Mr Dave has a good **turn of phrase**.

[Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/turn+of+phrase) says of this

> An eloquent style of writing or speaking.

and this suggests another way to talk about Mr Dave's ability:

> Mr Dave is a very [eloquent](https://www.lexico.com/definition/eloquent) writer.